# Bootstrap Button State

Tags: php, forms, button, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm building a one page website with Twitter Bootstrap 3.1.1.
It is a basic "contact us" form. What I want to achieve is if the form submission is successful, the submit button should read "success" and if there is an error it should read "Error!" Currently, the form submitted goes to a new undesigned basic html page.
HTML for button is

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

PHP for submission is

```
if($send_contact){
echo "Success!";
}
else {
echo "Error!";
}
```

Can I program the button using loading-state? 
I know nothing about ajax and thought might get some help here :)

EDIT : Im guessing my problem is that Im using a separate file to do the php processing. So the output is shown on that php page. But I really would want to keep it that way (i.e. use external php files) because I have two forms on the same page. Now wondering, if I can atleast get the output in a modal/pop up/alert on the same index page?

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="contactusform.php" id="contactusform" data-parsley-validate>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need javascript for this, or you need to use sessions. JS first (using jQuery library)

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //stop page from reloading
    var $this = $(this); //cache form element for use in ajax function
    $.ajax({
        url: '/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $this.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            $this.find('button[type="submit"]').text(data.msg);
        }
    });
});
```

Then in your PHP script, you'll change how you return the data:

```
   $ret = array();
   $ret['msg'] = 'Error!';
   if($send_contact){
       $ret['msg'] = 'Success!';    
   }
   echo json_encode($ret);
```

If using sessions, then you will change the button state as follows:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><?php isset($_SESSION['msg']) ?: 'Submit'; ?></button>
```

Which is using a ternary operator to evaulate the `$_SESSION['msg']` variable, and if true, uses the value of the session variable, otherwise, it uses 'Submit'.

You also need to ensure you use `session_start();` at the top of the page (before any white space or other erroneous data is output).

Then you need to modify your conditional statement once more:

```
$_SESSION['msg'] = 'Error!';
if($send_contact){
    $_SESSION['msg'] = 'Success!';    
}
header("Location: http://domain.tld/path/to/script.ext");
```

Finally, you should destroy the session variable after you generate the button's text, to ensure that if the page is reloaded, the button is reset

```
unset($_SESSION['msg']);
```

Comment: I tried the js / php option and I got this as the output {"msg":"Success!"} on a new page. Do I need to change the button html?

Comment: FYI :      <form role="form" method="POST" action="contactusform.php" id="contactusform" data-parsley-validate>

Comment: @TheAllSeeingI Wait, you're saying it printed `{"msg":"Success!"}` to the page as opposed to `Success!` using ajax? Are you sure the dataType is set to `json`?

Comment: @ Ohgodwhy : Yes. I've copied your code verbatim. So I believe its ajax and json.Right? How do I confirm its using ajax and data type is set to json?

Comment: @TheAllSeeingI Check the network tab of your web inspector (generally F12), you'll see the ajax request/response, and you can inspect it to see what the data returned was. i don't see why `data.msg` would contain a json encoded object its self that presented its self in plain text / html

Answer (score 0):

Just put the whole button inside your conditional check:

```
if($send_contact){
    echo '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Success!</button>';
} else {
    echo '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Error!</button>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this but it still goes onto a new page. I want the "Submit" button to change the state.